# How is par score used in any variants of Stableford competition?

Tags: rules, golf, scoring

I have seen some golf scoring systems that show the players' score in relation to par during Stableford competitions.

How is this calculated? The point of Stableford is to not worry about the number of strokes taken and just focus on the points. Is the par score in relation to the points scored or are the strokes still counted?

If the strokes are counted, how are blobs accounted for?

Comment: Certainly the intention is to focus on points, but there's still connection between shots taken and success (plus people like to see how the score relate to how they're playing as a whole), so they may show them. I'd guess they'd just count a "blob" of +2 or worse as a double bogey generally. For PGA golfers, triples and worse are quite rare. For some of us who are more "regular" schleps, a traditional round score will end up being wrong more often unless we play out the bad holes. But then there's more of a tendency to quit on bad holes even in the traditional scoring format for bad golfers!

Answer (score 1):

In a stableford match, a par (after handicap adjustment) would give you 2 points.

Therefore the par can be calculated as:

`(number-of-holes-played x 2) - current-points`